# PHP7 on macOS Sierra Beta Fails to Install

Tags: php, macos, macos-sierra

I currently have PHP 5.6.23 installed on my system.. However, I am trying to install PHP7 on my system (macOS Sierra Beta), I'm trying to do this with `brew install homebrew/php/php70`.

However, I get the following error:

```
$ brew install php70
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Installing php70 from homebrew/php
==> Downloading https://php.net/get/php-7.0.9.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
Already downloaded: /Users/Removed/Library/Caches/Homebrew/php70-7.0.9
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.9 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sy
Last 15 lines from /Users/Removed/Library/Logs/Homebrew/php70/01.configure:
checking for pthreads_lib...

Configuring SAPI modules
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS...

Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /usr/sbin/apxs follows:
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.

configure: error: Aborting

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues

These open issues may also help:
php70-yaf https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3328
Install PHP70: Incompatible library version https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3444
No solr available for php70 yet https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3454
brew install php70-redis https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2762
php70-imagick has warnings https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2766
Add head formula for php70-uploadprogress https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/3178
"brew upgrade" fails: php56 conflicting with php70 when upgrading phpmyadmin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2945
10.6.8 "brew install php70" failed with Error 139 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2708
Adds a new php70-gearman formula that updates php56-gearman https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/3120
Why does wp-cli formula try to install php56 if php70 is already there? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3179
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

The outcome of `brew doctor` is this:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

Any guidance/help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to use brew with a pre preleased MacOS version then you should take the time and read through their issues: [apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!. #3283](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3283)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ brew link apr-util --force
$ brew link apr --force
$ which apu-1-config
/usr/local/bin/apu-1-config
$ which apr-1-config
/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
$ sudo mkdir -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/ 
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/apu-1-config /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/apr-1-config /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: It supposedly works if you have Xcode installed. If you don't, and you use php-fpm (without apache) try this instead:

    `brew update && brew install apr apr-util && brew reinstall php70 --without-apache --with-fpm`

Comment: A little explanation with the magic would be great. apu/apr aren't even required by php?

Comment: This answer resolved the same error when configuring/building from source as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes

$ brew tap homebrew/versions

$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php

$ brew update && brew install apr apr-util

$ brew link apr-util --force
$ brew link apr --force

$ which apu-1-config

$ which apr-1-config

$ sudo mkdir -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/apu-1-config /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/apr-1-config /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/

$ brew install php70
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal,

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

will install php7 on macOS Sierra, I just tested.

Edit httpd.conf (located in /etc/apache2/) file.

Comment below line.

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```